Flutter local notification not working in backgroun in release mode
I have implemented fcm and added flutter local notification with action button for getting incomming call notification and it works on debug mode perfectly but it is not working in release mode. I have added all necessary permission. And I know most of os will kill background task but I need to know how to tackle those issues.Somebody please help me and I experianced similar issue in a live tracking app some os have killed the task after some time and navigation stopped
when a push notification comes Ineed to get call notification with ringtone with action button either with flutter local notification or flutter call kit.
Also Im doing a live tracking app I need to track continuosly. In that app I used geolocator , flutter background service etc the issue is navigation is getting stopped after some time in some phones
 import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:hope/core/services/local_storage.dart';
import 'package:hope/core/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:hope/core/view_model.dart/widgetprovider/bottomnav_provider.dart';
import 'package:hope/views/screens/matches/call_view.dart';
import 'package:hope/views/screens/matches/incomming_call.dart';
import 'package:hope/views/screens/notification/notification_view.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onSelectNotification(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
  final payload = notificationResponse.payload;

  if (payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(payload));

    log("Notification payload: ${data.toString()}");

    String messageType = data['type'];

    if (notificationResponse.actionId == 'accept_call') {
      // Stop the audio first
      await audioPlayer.stop();
      audioPlayer.dispose();

      // Cancel the notification
      if (notificationId != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId!);
      }

      // Navigate to the call view
      navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => CallView(
            channelId: data['channelId'],
            agoraToken: data['agora_token'],
            contactName: data['caller_name'],
          ),
        ),
      );

      return; // Early return to prevent further execution
    } else if (notificationResponse.actionId == 'reject_call') {
      // Stop the audio first
      await audioPlayer.stop();
      audioPlayer.dispose();

      // Cancel the notification
      if (notificationId != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId!);
      }

      // Since this is a reject action, do not navigate to any page
      log('Call Rejected');

      return; // Early return to prevent further navigation
    }

    // Handle other message types based on 'messageType'
    if (messageType == 'missed_call') {
      BottomNavProvider().setPage(3);
    } else if (messageType == 'chat') {
      navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => IncomingCallView(
            channelId: data['channelId'],
            agoraToken: data['agora_token'],
            contactName: data['channelId'],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (messageType == 'new_interest') {
      navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => IncomingCallView(
            channelId: data['channelId'],
            agoraToken: data['agora_token'],
            contactName: data['caller_name'],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (messageType == 'notification') {
      navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) =>
              NotificationView(), // Navigate to the notification screen
        ),
      );
    }
  } else {
    log("Notification payload is null or empty.");
  }
}

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
int? notificationId;

class PushNoti {
  String? _fcmToken;
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future<void> requestNotificationPermission() async {
    await _fcm.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    _fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();
    log('device FCM token is $_fcmToken');

    LocalStorage.setString({'fcmToken': _fcmToken.toString()});
    _fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();
  }

  Future<void> initPushNotification() async {
    _fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();
    log('device FCM token is $_fcmToken');

    LocalStorage.setString({'fcmToken': _fcmToken.toString()});

    // Handle incoming messages when the app is in the foreground
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) async {
      // showNotification(message!);
      // If it's a call type message, show the incoming call screen
      if (message!.data.isNotEmpty && message!.data['type'] == 'call') {
        audioPlayer.play();
        navigatorKey.currentState
            ?.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => IncomingCallView(
              channelId: message!.data['channelId'],
              agoraToken: message.data['agora_token'],
              contactName: message.data['caller_name'],
            ),
          ),
        )
            .then((_) {
          if (notificationId != null) {
            audioPlayer.stop();
            flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId!);
          }
        });
      } else {
        showNotification(message);
      }
    });

    // Handle notification taps when the app is in the background or terminated
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp
        .listen((RemoteMessage? message) async {});

    // Check if the app was opened from a terminated state due to a notification tap
    _fcm.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {});
  }
}

void showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

  if (message.data['type'] == 'call') {
    await audioPlayer.setAsset(
        'assets/ringtone/ringtone.mp3'); // Load the ringtone from assets
    audioPlayer.play();

    log('hello world tttt ${message.data.toString()}');
  }
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: message.data['type'] == 'call'
        ? AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'call_channel', // For call notifications
            'Incoming Call',

            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max,
            // sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('isa_63861'), // Custom sound for calls (optional)
            playSound: true,
            color: UiColor.primary,
            actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
              AndroidNotificationAction(
                'accept_call',
                'Accept',
                // icon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("ic_accept"),
                showsUserInterface: true,
              ),
              AndroidNotificationAction(
                'reject_call',
                'Reject',
                // icon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("ic_reject"),
                showsUserInterface: true,
              ),
            ],
          )
        : AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'important_notifications', // For other notifications
            'Important Notifications',
            importance: Importance.high,
            color: UiColor.primary,
            // sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("notification_sound"), // Optional custom sound
            actions: [], // No actions for other notifications (can be added dynamically)
          ),
    iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
      sound: 'default',
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    ),
  );

  if (notification != null && android != null) {
    notificationId = notification.hashCode;

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(notification.hashCode,
        notification.title, notification.body, platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: jsonEncode(message.data));
  }
}

Future<void> initLocalNotifications() async {
  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');

  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
  );

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
          (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
    // Handle background notification response here
    log('Background notification received from local notoifction: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
  }, onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onSelectNotification);
}

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // Show the notification first
  showNotification(message);

  // Check if the message type is 'call'
  if (message.data['type'] == 'call') {
    // Wait for 25 seconds
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 25));

    // Remove the notification after 25 seconds
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(message.notification.hashCode);
    log('Notification removed after 25 seconds for call type.');
  }
}

Future<void> firebaseMessagingForegroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (message.data['type'] == 'call') {
    await audioPlayer.setAsset(
        'assets/ringtone/ringtone.mp3'); // Load the ringtone from assets
    audioPlayer.play();
  } else {
    showNotification(message);
  }
}


Did you add these lines of code?
You need to configure a top level or static method which will handle the action:
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  // handle action
}

Specify this function as a parameter in the initialize method of this plugin:
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
        // ...
    },
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
);


i have added what you given but it is not for showing notificatin in background right. can you please refer the code given

You must put  notificationTapBackground in a top level above main()    @BibinJose   check document here  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

You are giving tips about notification click right i have added that just above the main function still the flutter local notification with action button doesnt shows in release mode

actually what i expected is when a new notification comes i need to show flutter local notificatoin with action buttons in even if the app is in background. you like whatsapp call notification i need a similar one to pick up call even if the app is killed or in background

Check this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming may help you

I have tried it already it also works in debug mode only not working in release mode

For me its resolved by unrestricting battery optimsation in app battery setting which can be find in devices setting-> apps -> ['app name']->battery and turn off toggole for (cancel permission when app in unused) . After changing this setup its start working

It doesnt work always i have tried it in another project for live tracking
